How to remove directory with special character in linux?
I accidentally created a folder with "-latr" name. How do I remove this?
I tried rmdir to remove the folder but since the name of folder is a linux command, It's not working and says "illegal option". Please help me.
Thank you!

@0stone0 No, the quotes don't help at all here.

Are you working on bash?
There are two easy ways to resolve this.

Using the absolute path:
~$ mkdir -p test/-ltr
~$ ls test/
-ltr
~$ rmdir test/-ltr
~$ ls test/
~$

Using 'rmdir --' (where '--' means end of options):
~$ cd test
test$ mkdir -- -ltr
test$ ls
-ltr
test$ rmdir -- -ltr
test$ ls
test$


Here's a good article explaining how this works:
https://www.tecmint.com/special-character-filenames-linux/#Dashed_Filename_in_Linux
TL;DR - the "rmdir" command, like most other commands, is first parsing its input for options parameters. Since they're usually passed as "-[letter]", this isn't working in your case.
I hope this helps.

Just to close off that thought. The hyphen char is not a special char to begin with, neither does it have anything to do with shell expansion, globbing, regex etc. so essentially, what @tripleee said.

as 0stone0 said:
rm -r -- '-latr'

generally, enclosing things in single quote ' works in such cases. it prevents things from being expanded & enterpreted as bash code

Nothing is being expanded. The problem is that an argument which starts with a hyphen is interpreted as an option to the command. No amount of quoting changes the first character from a hyphen to something else.
